# Mysql get next two dates grouped by ID

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table that has all eventIDs and event dates.  I need to get the next two dates, beyond the current date, for a specific subset of eventIDs.  I have tried many iterations and looked at many posts that return the top N results by GROUP - but I can't get any of those examples to work as those examples aren't using dates like I need to.  (ex: [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group))

```
+------------+-----+
| eDate      | ID  |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-10-27 | 1   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-03 | 1   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-10 | 1   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-17 | 1   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-24 | 1   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-12-01 | 1   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-12-08 | 1   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-10-27 | 2   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-03 | 2   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-10 | 2   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-17 | 2   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-24 | 2   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-12-01 | 2   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-12-08 | 2   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-10-27 | 3   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-03 | 3   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-10 | 3   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-17 | 3   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-11-24 | 3   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-12-01 | 3   |
+------------+-----+
| 2021-12-08 | 3   |
+------------+-----+

SELECT eDate,ID,COUNT(*) as eCount FROM myTable WHERE ID in (1,3) AND eDate >=CURDATE() GROUP BY ID,eDate HAVING eCount < 3 ;
```

This query doesn't work because the `GROUP BY ID,eDate` creates a unique pair, so its returning ALL entries for IDs 1 and 3 - all with a `eCount = 1`

Technically I don't actually need the `eCount` but it illustrates one of my many attempts to get the correct results.  If today was 2020-10-28, my desired results would be following.

```
+------------+-----+--------+
| eDate      | ID  | eCount |
+------------+-----+--------+
| 2021-11-03 | 1   | 1      |
+------------+-----+--------+
| 2021-11-10 | 1   | 2      |
+------------+-----+--------+
| 2021-11-03 | 3   | 1      | 
+------------+-----+--------+
| 2021-11-10 | 3   | 2      |
+------------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Use `ROW_NUMBER()` in CTE.

Comment: @Akina - I am using mysql 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a solution...I don't know how well it scales or if there are other caveats I need to think about, but it occurred to me I don't need to use GROUP BY because I am already looking for `ID in (1,3)`.  All I need to do count the number of IDs I am looking for and multiple it by 2 to set as the `LIMIT`

```
IE: 1,3 = LIMIT 4
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID IN (1,3) AND eDate>=CURDATE() ORDER BY eDate LIMIT 4 ;

IE: 1,3,11, 15 = LIMIT 8
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID IN (1,3,11,15) AND eDate>=CURDATE() ORDER BY eDate LIMIT 4 ;
```

This will grab ALL dates for those IDs, order them by the date...so the top 4 or top 8 will be all the records I need.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works only if you have 2 or more dates after current date. Observe this example, if one of you id only have 1 date appear after current date, the `LIMIT 4` in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID IN (1,3) AND eDate>=CURDATE() ORDER BY eDate LIMIT 4 ;
```

.. will populate another row with `ID=1`. The result might be this instead:

```
+------------+----+
|   eDate    | ID |
+------------+----+
| 2021-11-03 | 3  |
| 2021-11-03 | 1  |
| 2021-11-10 | 1  |
| 2021-11-17 | 1  |
+------------+----+
```

I'm guessing that's not what you want.

Following Akina's comment of *"Use ROW_NUMBER() in CTE"*, if you're on MySQL version that supports window function, this could be the query you need:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT eDate, ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY eDate) eCount
  FROM myTable WHERE eDate>=CURDATE()
  ORDER BY ID, eDate) 
SELECT * FROM cte 
WHERE eCount <=2;
```

You'll get all ID's date records that appear after current date with the flexibility  to define specific ID or not and without the need to use `LIMIT`. For older MySQL versions that doesn't support window function, you probably can emulate the same idea of using row number like this:

```
SELECT eDate, ID, rownum
FROM
   ( SELECT *,
           @rn:=CASE WHEN @i = ID AND eDate >= CURDATE()
                   THEN @rn + 1
                   ELSE 0 END AS rownum,
            @i := ID
        FROM myTable m  
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i:=0, @rn:=0)  r
       ORDER BY ID, eDate) v
 WHERE rownum > 0 AND rownum <= 2 
ORDER BY ID, eDate;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bdcf81a0e0887a0a695cc7487cd42c93)

Comment: I am on mysql 5.7, so I can't take advantage of new `row_number()` - but I see your point about getting extra rows for a particular ID if another ID only lists one date.  I will try out your second solution. and report back.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify the type of eDate, so if the eDate type is DATE (only date without time) I wish this can help you.

```
SELECT eDate, ID, COUNT(ID) AS eCount
FROM myTable
WHERE ID IN (1,3) -- This condition return just two ids (1 and 3)
        AND eDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE())) -- This condition return the next two dates, beyond the current date ( current date = GETDATE() )
GROUP BY ID, eDate 
HAVING eCount < 3 -- This condition ensure select rows just have count loser than 3;
```

But if the eDate type is DATETIME, you must convert it first. `CONVERT(DATE, eDate)`

Comment: this appears to be a SQL query, not mysql.  I converted it to mysql but it won't work anyway because your DATEADD is adding 2 more days to the current day....which is not what I am looking for.  I am looking for the next two schedule dates beyond the current day.  If today is 2020-10-28, your query would return 2021-10-29 & 2021-10-30, when (based on the data set I provided) it would need to return `2021-11-03 & 2021-11-10`